# Не передается ArrayList в фрагмент с помощью интерфейса Parcelable

Tags: android, android-fragment, arraylist

```
public class ContactInfo  implements Parcelable {
    protected int imageEnterprise;
    protected String nameEnterprise;
    protected String titleStreet;
    protected int imageLike;
    protected String amountLikes;
    protected String titleDate;
    protected String amountDays;

    public ContactInfo() { }
    private ContactInfo(Parcel in) {
        imageEnterprise = in.readInt();
        nameEnterprise = in.readString();
        titleStreet = in.readString();
        imageLike = in.readInt();
        amountLikes = in.readString();
        titleDate = in.readString();
        amountDays = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactInfo> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<ContactInfo>() {
        public ContactInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ContactInfo(in);
        }
        public ContactInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContactInfo[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(imageEnterprise);
        dest.writeString(nameEnterprise);
        dest.writeString(titleStreet);
        dest.writeInt(imageLike);
        dest.writeString(amountLikes);
        dest.writeString(titleDate);
        dest.writeString(amountDays);
    }
}
```

В `MainActivity` пишу следующий код :

```
  ArrayList<ContactInfo> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
  ContactInfo c = new ContactInfo();
  c.imageEnterprise = R.drawable.image_list;
  c.nameEnterprise = "Name";
  c.titleStreet = "Some street";
   c.imageLike = R.drawable.image_like;
   c.amountLikes = "45";
   c.titleDate = "3434";
   c.amountDays = "5";
    list1.add(c);
    TabFragment1 tabfragment1 = new TabFragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList("ttt", list1);
```

Comment: какая ошибка приходит?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: в общем   myList = null

Comment: а достаете во фрагменте как?

Comment: myList = this.getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ttt");

Comment: а если попробовать так getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("ttt")

Comment: та же ошибка(  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: В классе ContactInfo есть конструктор, который не используется:
private ContactInfo(Parcel in) - может быть в этом ошибка ?

Comment: Покажите полностью код где вы достаете массив из аргументов.

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в активити, где вы создаете фрагмент

```
tabfragment1.setArgum
```

Скопировал ваш код, все работает, во фрагменте

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

ArrayList<ContactInfo> myList;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ttt");
    myList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот код у меня есть!

Comment: скопировал ваш код, все работает, обновил ответ

Comment: я пробовал этот же код только в методе onCreateView! В этом ошибка получается ? и зачем отдельно писать  myList.size(); ? setArguments у меня есть конечно же
 спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: в onCreateView у меня тоже все работает нормально. myList.size() это я просто написал

Answer (score -1):

исправьте конструктор списка (добавьте класс) new ArrayList<**ContactInfo**>()

```
ArrayList<ContactInfo> list1 = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
```

Comment: то же самое происходит

Comment: Попробуйте изменить атрибуты класса с protected на private , а так же (или) для конструктора класса для parcel так же включите паблик. Строю предположения на основании этого ответа в схожем вопросе http://stackoverflow.com/a/6681784/1767246

Comment: изменил, добавл методы get и set для всех полей, менял доступ к конструктору, и вот этот код тоже пробовал (из ссылки):
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        myList  = extras.getParcelableArrayList("ttt");
ничего не помогло, по прежнему myList =  null

Comment: A     setArguments()    у Вас присутствует?

Comment: @Dmitry Обновите пример кода. В вопросе про setArguments() нет, как  и про this.getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ttt");  (а есть только в комментариях, картина не полная).

Comment: @Dmitry Выполучаете bundle через Extras Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(); а помещаете через putParcelableArrayList. Попробуйте помещать список через putParcelableArrayList**Extra** предположение строю на основании следующего вопроса http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138757/how-to-use-intent-putparcelablearraylistextra-method-and-the-parcelable-interf

Comment: setArguments я использую, хорошо, попробую, спасибо!